# eslint prettier require file rearrage

Tags: react-native, eslint, prettier

I am trying to put the `require('node-libs-react-native/globals');` on the very top of the file, but when I save the file, it uses eslint/prettier, it is rearrange it after the import.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

require('node-libs-react-native/globals'); // <= put this the top.
```

Any place I can configure in .eslint file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could disable the import/first rule for this file to allow the 'require' statement to remain above the list of imports:

```
/* eslint-disable import/first */
require('node-libs-react-native/globals');

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
```